# Regarding prediction of Decision Tree

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, decision-tree

How does Decision tree predict the out come on a new Data set. Lets say with the hyper parameters I allowed my decision tree to grow only to a certain extent to avoid over fitting. Now a new data point is passed to this trained model, so the new data point reaches to one of the leaf nodes. But how does that leaf node predict whether the data point is either 1 or 0? ( I am talking about Classification here).

Comment: This question is more befitting for Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Regardless, you can read about decision trees here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html .

Answer (score 0):

Well, you pretty much answered your own question. But just to the extension, in the last the data is labelled to either 0 or 1 is hgihly dependent on the type of algorithm you used, for example, ID3 , uses the mode value to predict. similarly C4.5 and C5 or CART have there different criteria based on info gain, ginni index etc etc....

In simplified terms, the process of training a decision tree and predicting the target features of query instances is as follows:

1. Present a dataset containing of a number of training instances characterized by a number of descriptive features and a target feature
2. Train the decision tree model by continuously splitting the target feature along the values of the descriptive features using a measure of information gain during the training process
3. Grow the tree until we accomplish a stopping criteria --> create leaf nodes which represent the predictions we want to make for new query instances
4. Show query instances to the tree and run down the tree until we arrive at leaf nodes
5. DONE - Congratulations you have found the answers to your questions

here is a link I am suggesting which explain the decision tree in very detail with scratch. Give it a good read -

https://www.python-course.eu/Decision_Trees.php

Comment: Thanks for the info, but my question is still unanswered. All the above says about how to build a model & prune etc. Lets say I use CART & use Gini index or Entropy. Lets say if I use RF, the prediction is done on majority voting. What is the method used in Decision tree for prediction?